# create a non-stop android listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I get some json data from server using `AsyncTask` and put it in a `ListView` using an `ArrayAdapter`. As I am getting a lot of data, please tell me how can I add an infinite scroll to my `ListView`. I mean to say, that when the `ListView` reaches its end, the data should be loaded automatically. I searched the web and tried a lot of things but can't do what I want to.

Here is my code

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    ArrayList<ContentSetter> postList;

    StringArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        new GetData().execute();
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
        btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");
        lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
        adapter = new StringArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, postList);

       lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        int pageed;
        String result = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://paradi3emusic.com/?json=get_posts&post_type=songs&count=15");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(code==200){
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    result += line;


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("posts");
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ContentSetter content = new ContentSetter();
                    JSONObject customfield = object.getJSONObject("custom_fields");
                    JSONArray playlist = customfield.getJSONArray("mylyrics1");
                    content.setPostId(playlist.getString(0));
                    postList.add(content);
                }
                in.close();
                return true;
            }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting err.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //TextView mahd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mahdi);
            if (!result)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this [EndlessRecyclerView](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/endless-recyclerview-onscrolllistener.html)

Comment: i need listview not recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

This concept is called lazy loading.

you need to do something like this:

1. listen for the event when user scrolls to the end of listview
2. make your webservice call and show user a progressbar at the footer of list.
3. update list with data once data is received from service call, remove progressbar.

[here is an example](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/23/simplest-lazy-loading-listview-android-data-populated-mysql-database-php/)

Comment: thanks but i'm new in android and i can't understand the codes that used in this link correctly can you edit my codes or give me new codes please?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is something similar to Pageing. What you need to do is :

1) Listen for event when user scroll to Bottom of Listview
2) Pull more data from server or any other source you want to.
3) When request is being made put some footer to your listview,example showing some progress dialog for user friendliness.
4) Update the data source with pulled information 
5) Set and Update your adapter  and remove the footer from the listview and You are done.

For Your Reference check this link:
https://chrisarriola.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/dynamic-data-with-listview-loading-footer/

Comment: Yes,refer the above code and follow the above steps,it would definitely help

Comment: can i use my current asynctask for step 2?

Comment: well,you can use your async task,but it would be better if you use a footer rather than blocking user by showing some dialog,which is not a good programming practice.

Comment: This is not a good practice,all i can do is give you reference regarding your issue.You need to solve.

Comment: ok so please tel me what is 'threshold' in this code 

if (firstVisibleItem = threshold) {
            pullMoreData();
        }
and why i get undefined error in android studio?

Comment: Threshold would be the value which tells whether the last item of your listview is visible or not

Comment: For Example  // Sample calculation to determine if the last 
            // item is fully visible.
             final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
           if(lastItem == totalItemCount) {
              if(preLast!=lastItem){ //to avoid multiple calls for last item
                Log.d("Last", "Last");
                preLast = lastItem;
              }
           }

Comment: i worked on it a lot it's worked but the problem is that the json data in my website isn't paged and all posts are in a page and as you see in my code 
paradi3emusic.com/json=get_posts&post_type=songs&count=15'
value of the count at the end of the url will set that how much post must be load from server but this tutorial is for paged json data